# Some queries causes BBDD Closed connection

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a web app deployed on a Jboss EAP 6 that uses Hibernate to access a SQL Server database.

Every time I look for a specific register I get the error:

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed**

Search for any other register works fine. Restarting JBoss seems to solve the problem. Now I can get the register data without problem.

What could be causing the Exception for that register? Should I focus on the code? On the network? On the datasources definition? On the DB configuration?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons, but very offten:

1. Look at your code, you maybe call close() method
2. Check out your connection string (NTLMv2?)
3. Check out MS SQL Server and their setting, DB servers looking for not active sessions and closing them.

Answer (score 0):

Below reasons can be possible

1. Long query which is hanging up Sql Server.
2. Using Too much joins in query.
3. Tables contain more data and you have make the query in which join is not proper.